# Catkin_Make Cmd Fail and Configuration Incomplete

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, catkin

I am new to the Linux environment and I trying to do catkin_make but I got this issue.

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'proj1'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(proj)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   log_setup
--   log
--   program_options
--   thread
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   regex
--   chrono
--   atomic
/usr/include
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_log_setup.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_log.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
crypto_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "proj1-test" in directory /home/proj/src/proj1
    linked by target "CameraNode" in directory /home/proj/src/proj1

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/proj/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I already tried to install

```
libcrypto++6_5
libpthread
openssl
python-crypto
```

but still having the issue. May I know what I am missing?

My environment: Ubuntu (16.4) and64.

Comment: It seems you forgot to install `-dev` packages. E.g. [libcrypto++-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libcrypto++-dev).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I already install this library but still having the issue.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, May I know is there any way how can I check what is missing?

Comment: NOTFOUND variable `crypto_LIBRARIES` most likely means that crypto library has no been found. Searching a package by file `libcrypto.so` finds the package [libssl-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libssl-dev) .

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks u. I just need to install this libcrypto and libssl -dev and other dependencies. after that Now OK. Thank u.